# jQuery.ajax() call successful if I don't wrap the callback in a function() {}, fails otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amazon-s3

I am making an ajax call to Amazon S3 (with CORS set up properly, I believe).

When I run this, error and complete both get called.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/netanalytics-prototyping/test.csv',
      dataType: 'text/csv',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function() {
                 console.log("success"),
      }
      error: function() {
              console.log("error")
      },
      complete: function() {
                  console.log("complete")
      }
  });
```

When I run this, all 3 get called.

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/netanalytics-prototyping/test.csv',
      dataType: 'text/csv',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: console.log("success"),
      error: function() {
              console.log("error")
      },
      complete: function() {
                  console.log("complete")
      }
  });
```

Can someone explain what's going on, and perhaps show me how to operate on the data that I am getting from S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of `success` should be a `function()`

From [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation

> success
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

In your second example `console.log("success")`, will be executed when JavaScript interprets your code. So this does not mean your ajax call is success

So `console.log("success")` will be excuted and the returned value (if any) will be assigned to $.ajax `success` handler.

`$.ajax.complete()` will be called no matter ajax call fails or succeeded.

Your code has some syntax error, please see the below corrected code.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/netanalytics-prototyping/test.csv',
      dataType: 'text/csv',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function() {
                 console.log("success");
      },
      error: function() {
              console.log("error");
      },
      complete: function() {
                  console.log("complete");
      }
  });
```

Server is returning 403 (Forbidden)

Hitting the URL directly is also giving Access denied message

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/netanalytics-prototyping/test.csv

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>4D1ECAE7D1971C85</RequestId>
<HostId>
NPT4dfJSGeGQ/kUgv0SGnFwH52lDU69L8+5a5kvPJewFTw/q+Fu+A+lYVpJ7TgV3noDZHDaCZcg=
</HostId>
</Error>
```